# Javascript toLocaleTimeString() not working

Tags: javascript, datetime

Hello I have a piece of code

```
var date = new Date("11/12/2014 02:58:11 UTC");

console.info(date.toString());

console.info(date.toLocaleTimeString());

console.info(date.toLocaleDateString());
```

and display:

```
Tue Nov 11 2014 16:58:11 GMT-1000 (Hawaiian Standard Time)

9:58:11 AM

11/12/2014
```

My time zone is `(UTC-10:00) Hawaii`

`date.toString();` displays correctly, but `toLocaleTimeString()`, `toLocaleDateString()` displays incorrect output

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: I just tested your code and run in my local . For me it is giving correct output.I am not sure what library internally you are using.can you provide more details

Answer (score 7):

You can provide the time zone in the `options` parameter to `toLocaleTimeString()`:

```
date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US',{timeZone:'America/Adak'})
```

The time zone has to be specified from the IANA time zone database, which is a little odd... but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like so:

```
dateObj.toLocaleTimeString([locales[, options]])

console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US'));
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation, a locale string of 'hi' is 'Hindi' not 'Hawaii'.  India Standard time is UTC+5:30, not quite right to get UTC+7 answer though.

Comment: @Scott my app used in many time zone and console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US')); does not display my local time